# Android Studio / Kotlin: cannot run app on an physical device ("Couldn't terminate the existing process for...")

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin, and currently building my very first app (I am not experienced at all on the topic).

I successfully managed to customize my android phone and my android studio and achieved to launch the app I am currently working on a few times.

However, I now run into an error when trying to launch my app on my physical device. I get the following message: "Couldn't terminate the existing process for com.example.diceroller.", as if it was still running. The icons to launch/stop the app also seem to be in a state where the app is running on the device.

[image]

I have tried the following, without result:

- close all running apps on the phone
- reboot the phone
- restart Android Studio
- deactivate/reactivate USB debugging on the phone

The app does work fine on a virtual device.

Could you please give me any lead to follow to try and be able to test my app on a physical device? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Pierre Masse for posting the question in a detailed format, which made it easier for me to identify that I was facing the exact same issue.

I tried all the steps in the same order as mentioned by @Pierre Masse, however the outcome remained the same (unsuccessful).

I also followed the solution posted by @Muhammad Rio, unfortunately this too didn't work in my case.

This is how I resolved the issue.

- Delete the physical device from the Android studio Device Manager (When the phone isn't connected).
- Deactivate USB debugging on the phone.
- Now reconnect the phone using the USB cable where it is detected by the computer\laptop\Mac as a normal device (Storage\USB charging)
- Now reactivate USB debugging on the phone.
- Once the phone is listed again under physical devices in Android Studio Manager, run the app. It should run normally.

Thought of sharing this, so that a beginner like me doesn't get demotivated at the first roadblock in his mobile development journey.

Cheers to both Pierre and Muhammad for their inputs.

Comment: Hi @cool1, thanks for this answer. I cannot however validate that it would have worked in my context (as I've moved to developping in Flutter rather than Kotlin). Thanks for the tentative answer anyway!

Comment: Hey, no worries @Pierre Masse. Thanks for taking the effort to reply :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill the daemon, open your `terminal` and write this

```
adb kill-server
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad, thanks for your answer, but it did not work. `adb kill-server` did restart the daemon, but I am still stuck in the same state afterwards.